# How to detect gaps between integer sequence in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to figure out a way to determine if there are gaps between invoice numbers in a data set:

Here's an example of the table/series

```
Invoice #
1001
1002
1003
1005
1010
1011
1012
```

So I have gaps between 1003 and 1005, 1005 and 1010

I would like to evaluate the list of values in a pandas data frame and return something like this

```
Gaps Found

Start Value | End Value | Integers Missing

1003        | 1005      | 1

1005        | 1010      | 4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''Invoice
1001
1002
1003
1005
1010
1011
1012'''))
df['start'] = df['Invoice']
df['end'] = df['Invoice'].shift(-1)
df['gap'] = df['Invoice'].shift(-1) - df['Invoice'] -1
print(df[df['gap'] >0])
```

Comment: This does not match with expected output at all.

Comment: `shift(-1)` buddy

Comment: yeah thanks... i missed it. you deserve a vote for being quick and smart!, anyway your answer isnt vectorized...

Comment: Yup your answer takes less time, you deserve upvote too : )

Comment: Nice answer !! +1.

Comment: This works, thank you. I think the assumption in this program is that the invoices are sorted ascending. I would just need to sort my dataframe before running this program. Right?

Comment: of course if the order matters for your expected output

Answer (score 2):

I guess following is what you have been looking for,

```
df[['Start','End','Integers Missing']]=df.apply(lambda row,df: pd.Series([row['Invoices'],df.loc[row.name,'Invoices'],(df.loc[row.name,'Invoices'] - row['Invoices'] -1)]), axis=1, args=[df.shift(-1)])

df[df['Integers Missing']>0].astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    invoices    Start   End Integers Missing
2   1003    1003    1005    1
3   1005    1005    1010    4
```